# Booting from a hard disk partition .. update-grub?

Tags: grub

I am trying to install Debian by using a hard disk partition only. I want to install on `/dev/sda6`

I used `dd` to copy a Debian ISO image to `/dev/sda5`, a newly formatted `ext4` partition.

I ran `update-grub` hoping for it to find a kernel image on `/dev/sda5` but it did not.

Is there any way that I can make `/dev/sda5` a boot option?

Comment: I'm not sure if you can boot an ISO from a disk just like that. Even if it booted somehow it wouldnt find a cd/dvd drive and be confused... Probably you would at least need isolinux or similar to do that.

Comment: Umm why are you asking the same thing again here. Please get back to the original thread.

Comment: ok cool. i am thinking that this is not easy if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that, standard grub (grub2) knows about several filesystem formats, but it cannot look into files that contain filesystems on another filesystem.

Comment: If you dd an iso onto the partition, technically there is no file there, but it wont work either I believe.